# Interpreting periodogram

Tags: r, time-series, spectral-analysis

I have some simulated data following `sin`, where the pattern repeats roughly every 25th observation.

```
n <- 200
x <- sin(1:n / 4) + rnorm(n, 0, .1)
```

When I look at the periodogram in R using `spectrum`, it suggests a peak around frequency **0.04**. How do I relate this to my series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scale of the horizontal axis is in cycles per unit of time; 0.5 at the right end is the Nyquist frequency (a cycle lasting two units of time, hence 0.5 cycles per unit).

Your peak at about 0.04 corresponds to about 0.04 cycles per unit of time, or a full cycle per about 25 units of time, as you mention.